# Get Outlook Message (using VSTO, EWS or Redemption) with only the Internet Message ID value

Tags: c#, vsto, exchangewebservices, outlook-redemption

I've got the Internet Message ID values from x number of emails. I need to write some C# code to open and display the Outlook messages with only the Internet Message ID value to identify them.

Is it possible to get an Outlook message (using VSTO, EWS or Redemption) with only the Internet Message ID value to identify the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, if you know the folder where the message resides, you can use `RDOFolder.Items.Find(" ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F"" = '<SomeValue>' ")`